# Will internal tracking links (redirecting to outbound URLs) hurt my Google rankings?

Tags: seo, google, links, click-tracking

On my site I have multiple internal tracking links (eg. /track/link/12) which direct the user to an internal tracking script which subsequently redirects the user to some outbound URL. Common practice.

All outbound links are like this on my site.

Will this affect or hurt my rankings with Google?

Answer (score 1):

No. Redirects are followed just fine as long as they aren't too deep or done in such a fashion that are known not to be followed by search engines. Plus this would just affect the sites being linked to. If the links aren't followed then they won't get credit as being linked to.

Comment: I have rel="nofollow" on all of these links (because they are affiliate referral links), so the search engines will not (should not) follow them. Does that change anything? Will that hurt my rankings?

Comment: The search engines won't follow them.